# Beginning Web Development on Plan 9

Tags: html, web-applications, plan-9

I've been wanting to program for the Plan 9 operating system for a while. I'd really like to play around with a web app there. Of course, the only language I know for Plan 9 is C, and that doesn't seem ideal for web development. I also understand that it doesn't run apache or mysql either.

What is the best way to start coding web apps on Plan 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Kenji Arisawa's [Pegasus](http://plan9.aichi-u.ac.jp/netlib/pegasus/) ([paper](http://lsub.org/iwp9/cready/pegasus-5.pdf)) webserver for Plan 9.

Plan 9 may have a reputation for being C-only, but several langauges, including Scheme, Ruby, Python, and Perl have been ported. Check out the [Contrib Index](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/Contrib_index/index.html) for the code.

Finally, start reading the Plan 9 [white papers](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/Documentation/index.html) so that you can understand its philosophy. If you want to do net-related things, the file protocol [9p](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/contrib/uriel/doc/charles/servers.pdf) is essential.

Answer (score 3):

[Werc](http://werc.cat-v.org) is a web framework designed to run on Plan 9 (and Plan 9 from User Space). It is built using the rc shell and following the classic Bell Labs 'tool philosophy'.

Instead of a database, in keeping with the Unix tradition it uses plain text files stored in a file system.